# Wicket: Links in mutable ListView/DataView

Tags: java, wicket

Let's say I have a set of items that I need to display in a table/list. The set is highly mutable, because background-jobs and other users access the same data.

Now the resulting output has to contain links that trigger actions on the underlying data. These actions might remove an item from the set, but don't always do so.

Since the model of a ListView (I'm not quite sure about DataView right now) is index-based, it's bound to fail in such situations. I get errors when I click a link that refers to the wrong object because the order or size of the underlying list has changed.

So what I need are links that always refer to the natural ID of the object they are supposed to operate on. When a link gets rendered to the user, I want that rendered link to always refer to the same object, no matter what happens to the set that was used at render time.

The easiest solution that comes to mind is using a stateless link only containing the action and the id, leading the user to another page. But this has the obvious disadvantage that I loose all the benefits the Component-system provides in the first place.

How would you solve this problem?

Comment: Can you show us some fialing code? When you keep the data in your lists model and the link data in your listitems model it shouldn't matter if some indices fail. It will matter if you just store an index in you listitems model and try to reaccess the data but this would be a problem everywhere not just in wicket and/or java.

Answer (score 0):

DataView is non-index based, see IDataProvider#model(), so you where pretty close to the right answer.